# How prototype works in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know that there is question already, but I have to make this clear.

```
function Animal(species) {
    this.species = species;
}
Animal.prototype.getSpecies = function() {
    return "Animal is " + this.species;
};


(function() {
    var animal1 = new Animal("Snake");
    var animal2 = new Animal("Wolf");
    var animal3 = new Animal("Tiger");
}());
```

And this is how I understand.
[image]

Function/Method getSpecies() is shared between all Animal objects in prototype object.
Did I understand correctly?

Is it correct to say that `_Proto_` is pointer to prototype object ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes. ----------------

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you are right, that is how it works! **But** `__proto__` is not a pointer, it is a reference and its use is depricated. In Javascript real pointers do not exist, but references do.

If you create a Type that inherits from Animal like this:

```
function FastAnimal () {
    Animal.call(this, 'extreme-fast');
}

FastAnimal.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
FastAnimal.prototype.constructor = FastAnimal;
FastAnimal.prototype.getSpeed = function () { return '1MILLION'; };


var fa = new FastAnimal();


fa.getName = function () {}
```

Than a lookup for a property or Method in `fa` will go that way:

1. does `fa` has this OWN Property (as getName)
2. does it exist in `FastAnimal.prototype` (getSpeed)
3. does it exist in `Animal`

In general: This lookup goes on as long as there are `prototype`s on the way. However, that is what happens under the hood and called the prototype chain.

N.B.:

If you would like to loop over the properties of a given Object, there are two ways:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    //do stuff
}
```

That includes properties of the prototype and normally not what people want, that's why

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

is a common pattern, **BUT** there is a new type of loop coming up and hopefully usable in the near future.

```
for (var prop of obj) {}
```

This one also explicitly excludes properties of the object’s prototype.

Comment: What is point of line: FastAnimal.prototype.constructor = FastAnimal; ?

Comment: That's kind of a fix… Object.create(…) copies all properties from the Animals prototype to FastAnimals one and that includes the constructor, so you one need to fix it.

Comment: `for (var prop of obj) {}` is *ES6*  and isn't supported in Internet Explorer for example. MDN marks it as *experimental technology*. Do not use in production. As you already said

Comment: that's why I wrote »hopefully usable in the near future«…

Comment: Yes, updated my comment, but the real purpose to post a reference to ES6.

Comment: If I call fa.species I get "extreme fast". But if I call fa.getSpecies I get "Animal is undefined". Why is undefined?

Comment: yes i see what problem is. getSpecies() must be called as function. with '()'

Comment: But is strange that string ""Animal is" is written.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you right 
If you use
animal1.getSpecies == animal2.getSpecies true

anima2.getSpecies == animal3.getSpecies true

Only one copy of function and prototype exists